# How can I change from appcompat activity to Activity in Android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

I'm trying to figure out how to change from AppCompatActivity to Activity in Android studio.

Comment: why do you need that to change ?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {}
```

to

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {}
```

---

*Note*: If you want to change the `AppCompatActivity` because it cannot resolve it and you get and error. Add this line in dependencies in your `build.gradle` file:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
```